# Chai Try Assert More Than Once Before Failing?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chai, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm doing a PUT request to an API, then I'm doing a GET request to see if what I PUT is there. The problem is that the API can take time between the PUT and GET requests for the data to propagate to be seen by the GET request. The testing framework I am using I just added waits, but I know this is not desirable, and I'm already seeing slow or failing tests as a result. To try to remove the waits I added the following, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

```
// A function that simply tries x times for the checkingFunction to return a truthy value.
async function waitForCorrectApiResponse(checkingFunction, maxTries = 5, waitPeriod = 3000) {
  let tries = 0;
  while(maxTries > tries) {
    const apiResponse = await checkingFunction();
    if(apiResponse) {
      return apiResponse;
    }
    // A wait method
    await t.wait(waitPeriod);
    tries ++;
  }
}

const response = waitForCorrectApiResponse(async function(){
  const apiResponse = await getApiResponse() // some random get API response function
  if (apiResponse.body.hasOwnProperty('whatever') {
    return apiResponse;
  }
}

// Then do Chai assertions against response.....
```

For example off the top of my head I would like to be able to do something like the following...Basically, try a set of Chai assertions against a value x times, and each time if false reset the value.

```
async function waitForCorrectApiResponse(checkingFunction, maxTries = 5, waitPeriod = 3000) {
  let tries = 0;
  while(maxTries > tries) {
    const apiResponse = await checkingFunction();
    if(apiResponse) {
      return apiResponse;
    }
    // A wait method
    await t.wait(waitPeriod);
    tries ++;
  }
}

const response = waitForCorrectApiResponse(async function(){
  const apiResponse = await getApiResponse() // some random get API response function
  Chai.expect(apiResponse).to.have.property('whatever');
  // Rest of Chai assertions.....
}
```

**Update:**
So I have been able to make the following, which I think is a little better but wondering if there is something even better?

```js
    async function retryChai(apiCall, assertions, maxTries = 5, waitPeriod = 3000) {
      let tries = 0;
    
      while (maxTries > tries) {
        tries ++;
        const apiResponse = await apiCall();
    
        try {
         const ok = await assertions(apiResponse);
         return ok; 
        }
        catch (e) {
          if (maxTries === tries) {
           assertions(apiResponse)
          }
    
        }
        await t.wait(waitPeriod);
      }
    }
    
    retryChai(
      async function (){
        // returns API response
      },
      function (response) {
        // Put chai asserts here. i.e....
        chai.expect(response.body.documents).to.be.empty;
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you are using the TestCafe Framework. TestCafe has a built-in [assertion](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html) mechanism. So, it's not required to use the Chai library.

In general, your approach looks fine. It's difficult to say precisely how to improve your code since you shared just a small piece of code, not a working example.
In my opinion, your first approach is more practical since you split the API request and assertion into different functions.